# create tabs in page

Tags: ionic2, ionic2-tabs

I would like to create tabs like these on a page:

[image] As you see Voortgang and pijnniveau are my tabs in the page itself but if I set them like this:

```
export class ProgressPage {    
    tab1Root = HomePage;
    tab2Root = SchemaPage;
```

and than in my html template do this:

```
      <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="light">
        <ion-title>{{viewTitle}}</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button ion-button [disabled]="isToday" (click)="today()">Today</button>
            <button ion-button (click)="changeMode('month')">M</button>
            <button ion-button (click)="changeMode('week')">W</button>
            <!--<button ion-button (click)="changeMode('day')">D</button>-->
            <button ion-button (click)="loadEvents()">Load Events</button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="has-header">  
  <!--<template #template let-showEventDetail="showEventDetail" let-selectedDate="selectedDate" let-noEventsLabel="noEventsLabel"></template>-->

    <calendar [eventSource]="eventSource"
              [calendarMode]="calendar.mode"
              [currentDate]="calendar.currentDate"
              (onCurrentDateChanged)="onCurrentDateChanged($event)"
              (onEventSelected)="onEventSelected($event)"
              (onTitleChanged)="onViewTitleChanged($event)"
              (onTimeSelected)="onTimeSelected($event)"
              step="30">
    </calendar>


  <ion-list inset>
    <ion-list-header>{{ viewTitle }}</ion-list-header>
    <ion-item>
      <h3>Frans van Brugge <span class="date">9 juni 2017</span></h3>
      <p>Fysiotherapie afsrpaak</p>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <h3>Frans van Brugge <span class="date">9 juni 2017</span></h3>
      <p>Fysiotherapie afsrpaak</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>


<ion-tabs color="light" tabsPlacement="top">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Missies"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Beloningen"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

But this will looks like this, you see the `tabRoot` pages under the active page:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go to your app.componet.ts file and set the rootPage to ProgressPage. (If this is the opening screen of your app)

If you are using a login screen or if you are navigating from another screen to this screen, then ensure that you are pushing the ProgressPage in the navCtrl.

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Its not about the bottom tabs these are working, but now I want to add 2 tabs in my page but dont know how..